# Binding to an expression

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I have an onscreen numeric keypad to type a PIN. What I want to do is disable the buttons when four digits of PIN are entered. I can certainly do this with code pretty easily, but it seems to me to be the sort of thing that should be done with binding.

Something like:

```
<Button Style="Whatever" IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=PinBox ???}"/>
```

It seems there isn't a way to do that (which to be honest seems rather primitive to me.) So I considered the alternative, which is a plain property on the underlying Window class. But I'm not sure how to bind to it. Do I need to specify the class itself as its own data context, or do I need to extract the PIN string into a View Model?

And subsequently, how do I get the plain property to update the GUI?

I suppose I could defined a view model class and have a dependency property called "ButtonsEnabled" but it seems kind of heavyweight for such a simple problem.

Let me know if I am missing something.

Comment: you can try [**binding your component (button) to a function**](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/b92178bc-bc1a-4ec0-ad94-b86bbf2ea56a)

Comment: If you use `RelayCommand` then you can specify a bool property for the `canExecute` parameter and invoke `CanExecuteChanged`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can write a converter which return boolean depending on digits in TextBox

The XAML fo r button would be

```
<Button Content="Test" IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=PinBox,Path=Text,Converter={StaticResource DigitsToBoolConverter}}" Grid.Row="1" Height="20" Width="100"></Button>
```

where PinBox is the textbox name used to enter pin.

The Converter function is

```
 public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
 {
     return value.ToString().Length >= 4;
 }
```

Comment: 88 characters of XAML for something that *should* be something like just `IsEnabled="{ PinBox.Length == 4 }"`. WPF has a long way to go...

Answer (score 9):

Another way using [commands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx#id0090030):

XAML:

```
<Button Content="2" Style="Whatever" Command={Binding MyCommand} CommandParamater="2"/>
```

ViewModel:

```
public ICommand MyCommand { get; private set; }
public string PinNumber { get; private set; }
public void Init()
{
  MyCommand = new RelayCommand(
    param => AddPinNumberDigit(param),
    param => CanAddPin);
}
private void AddPinNumberDigit(string digit)
{
  PinNumber += digit;
}
public bool CanAddPin { 
  get
  {
    return PinNumber.Length < 3;
  }
}
```

Comment: I love this answer and learned a lot from it, but ultimately I actually used the converter. I wish I could accept both, but I did upvote you.

Answer (score 4):

Nope, your not missing anything, WPF out of the box bindings do not support expressions.

There has been some people implementing their own classes that add this type of functionality:
http://www.11011.net/wpf-binding-expressions

But really, this is what the ViewModel pattern is for. Use it, it's not heavyweight.

Comment: Given this is over 5 years old I'm not surprised :)

Comment: @brainydexter you could use the wayback machine? https://web.archive.org/web/20160313063004/http://www.11011.net/wpf-binding-expressions But given its over 5 years old I would suggest a fresh google 'wpf binding including expression' or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Create a [converter](http://wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html) that will return true or false based on PinBox.Text.Length.

Your xaml would then become:

```
<Button Style="Whatever" IsEnabled={Binding ElementName=PinBox, Converter={StaticResource yourConverter}}/>
```